# Indexing Error in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I'm unable to find out the mistake here in indexing. I am sure this must be some silly mistake. I want to set 'td' values of those rows to 0 whose 'block' size is 1. I'm first finding out such rows and then using those indices to set the values of the column 'td' to 0.
Here is the sample data set. Here, except block no 5,7,8 all the other block values should be set to 0 in 'td' column.

```
    Sid     Itemid  Block       td
0     1  214536502      1  180.591
1     1  214536500      2    37.13
2     1  214536506      3  133.308
3     1  214577561      4      NaN
4     2  214662742      5   41.759
5     2  214662742      5   78.073
6     3  214576500      6      NaN
7     4  214821275      7   26.002
8     4  214821275      7   28.199
9     5  214821371      8   42.289
10    5  214821371      8   45.193
```

Here is my code. I'm getting unexpected output.

```
j=k.groupby('Block').Sid.count()==1
te=k['Block'][j[j].index].index
k['td'][te]=0
```

Expected Output-

```
    Sid     Itemid  Block       td
0     1  214536502      1       0
1     1  214536500      2       0
2     1  214536506      3       0
3     1  214577561      4       0
4     2  214662742      5   41.759
5     2  214662742      5   78.073
6     3  214576500      6       0
7     4  214821275      7   26.002
8     4  214821275      7   28.199
9     5  214821371      8   42.289
10    5  214821371      8   45.193
```

Comment: `[j[j].index].index` is not valid syntax..

Comment: it would helpful if you would provide a sample input data as text

Comment: @MaxU Added sample dataset

Comment: what is expected output?

Comment: do you mean "whose block size" or "whose block count" is 1?

Comment: @MaxU Block Size I meant.

Comment: @ADITYAAWALKAR, check Alexander's solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you would do the assignment:

```
k.ix[(k.groupby('Block').Sid.transform('count') == 1), 'td'] = 0

>>> k
    Sid     Itemid  Block      td
0     1  214536502      1   0.000
1     1  214536500      2   0.000
2     1  214536506      3   0.000
3     1  214577561      4   0.000
4     2  214662742      5  41.759
5     2  214662742      5  78.073
6     3  214576500      6   0.000
7     4  214821275      7  26.002
8     4  214821275      7  28.199
9     5  214821371      8  42.289
10    5  214821371      8  45.193
```

Transform returns a series the same length as the dataframe.  Then find find those that equal one, and use `loc` to set the column `td` at those index locations to the value of zero.

Comment: you can simplify it a little bit: `k.ix[(k.groupby('Block').Sid.transform('count') == 1), 'td'] = 0
`

Comment: Always like to simplify.  Thanks.

Comment: @Alexander : Perfect. Exactly what I wanted. Thank you. I'm trying to understand transform function here. I was initially confused since groupby will return a smaller sized dataframe while the initial dataframe k is large. On running the code I found that transform applies the given argument(count) on all the members of a group. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You are correct. As indicated in my description above, transform returns a series the same length as the original dataframe.